# Using XSLT to transform XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following set XML content (basically, multiple lines  with three items

in it) which I want to transform as follows:
Instead of having:

```
<line><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></line>
<line><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></line>
<line><li>x</li><li>y</li><li>z</li></line>
```

I would like to have:

```
<line>
<item1>col1<item1><li>1</li>
<item2>col2<item1><li>2</li>
<item3>col3<item1><li>3</li>
</line>
<line>
<item1>col1<item1><li>a</li>
<item2>col2<item1><li>b</li>
<item3>col3<item1><li>c</li>
</line>
<line>
<item1>col1<item1><li>x</li>
<item2>col2<item1><li>y</li>
<item3>col3<item1><li>z</li>
</line>
```

Basically adding a column for ech line.
Does XSLT help achieving that result?
Many thanks.

Comment: That's invalid XML!

Comment: Yes, the task you describe is trivially soluble with XSLT.  If you have tried to solve it with XSLT and failed, we can help you if you show what you've tried.  If you haven't tried to solve it but just wanted to check before investing time in reading an XSLT tutorial, then good luck to you and yes, like any Turing-complete language XSLT can perform simple tree restructurings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a slightly modified verion. My input XML is:

```
<message>
<line number="1"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></line>
<line number="2"><li>x</li><li>y</li><li>z</li>
</line>
<line number="3"><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>
</line>
</message>
```

And my XSLT is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/message/line">

number: <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
position: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
all items: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
item[3]: <xsl:value-of select="li[3]"/>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This yields:

```
number: 1
position: 1
all items: 123
item[3]: 3

number: 2
position: 2
all items: xyz
item[3]: z

number: 3
position: 3
all items: abc
item[3]: c
```

My initial thoughts were to put the all items in a variable and then do the second nested for-each on that variable. But what it yields is 123 (for the first line), ommitting the

tags. Interestingly, when I try with the following XPath on the message:

```
/message/line[1]/li
```

I obtain:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
```

which is the desired outcome.
In my XSLT, I tried to replace "select="."" with "select="li[position()]"" but it would only return the 1st item of each line.

Is there any explanation and what should I change to get the same outcome as my xPath?

Comment: Can you share the desired output for the updated XML that you have mentioned in your answer?